# dplyr and aggregation with summarise; a simple way to get mean at diffrent levels of aggregation

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, data-management

I am interested in the total mean, and the mean within different conditions, of some measurements preferably using `dplyr`'s `summarise` function.

I'll illustrate my question in the following. Say I have some data, borrowed form [this this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/),

```
dta <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
 subject sex condition measurement
       1   M   control         7.9
       1   M     cond1        12.3
       1   M     cond2        10.7
       2   F   control         6.3
       2   F     cond1        10.6
       2   F     cond2        11.1
       3   F   control         9.5
       3   F     cond1        13.1
       3   F     cond2        13.8
       4   M   control        11.5
       4   M     cond1        13.4
       4   M     cond2        12.9
') # ; dta
```

I now want the mean for each `sex` and the mean by `sex` for each `condition`. I know how to get it for each `condition`, like this.

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr) 
dta %>% 
  group_by(sex, condition) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(measurement)
)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   sex [?]
#>      sex condition  mean
#>   <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1      F     cond1 11.85
#> 2      F     cond2 12.45
#> 3      F   control  7.90
#> 4      M     cond1 12.85
#> 5      M     cond2 11.80
#> 6      M   control  9.70
```

But, this does not give me the aggregate mean for both sexes. To get this I either have to run a separate call, i.e.

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(measurement)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      sex     mean
#>   <fctr>    <dbl>
#> 1      F 10.73333
#> 2      M 11.45000
```

or deconstruct data structure. Like this,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyr)
dta_wide <- spread(dta, condition, measurement)

dta_wide %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_tot = mean(cond1 + cond2 + control)/3,
    mean_cond1 = mean(cond1),
    mean_cond2 = mean(cond2),
    mean_control = mean(control)        
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      sex mean_tot mean_cond1 mean_cond2 mean_control
#>   <fctr>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1      F 10.73333      11.85      12.45          7.9
#> 2      M 11.45000      12.85      11.80          9.7
```

This gives me an output with both the over all mean by `sex` and the individual mean by `condition`.

However, both running two separate calls and deconstructing data seems unnecessarily cumbersome. Isn't there a simply way to add a categorical variable, here `condition`, as the `by` variable and at the same time keep the aggregate information, here mean by `sex`? Maybe I am overlooking something logical and shouldn't be messing with data like this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to calculate the two summaries separately, then join back:

```
dta %>% 
    group_by(sex, condition) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(measurement)) %>% 
    inner_join(
        group_by(dta, sex) %>% 
        summarise(mean_tot = mean(measurement))
    )

# Joining, by = "sex"
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   sex [?]
#     sex condition  mean mean_tot
#  <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      F     cond1 11.85 10.73333
#2      F     cond2 12.45 10.73333
#3      F   control  7.90 10.73333
#4      M     cond1 12.85 11.45000
#5      M     cond2 11.80 11.45000
#6      M   control  9.70 11.45000
```

Or use `group_by` twice:

```
dta %>% 
    group_by(sex, condition) %>% 
    summarise(s = sum(measurement), n = n()) %>% 
    group_by(sex) %>% 
    transmute(condition, mean_tot = sum(s) / sum(n), mean = s / n)

# Adding missing grouping variables: `sex`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   sex [2]
#     sex condition mean_tot  mean
#  <fctr>    <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1      F     cond1 10.73333 11.85
#2      F     cond2 10.73333 12.45
#3      F   control 10.73333  7.90
#4      M     cond1 11.45000 12.85
#5      M     cond2 11.45000 11.80
#6      M   control 11.45000  9.70
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both options you suggest produce the total mean within `sex` three times. Kinda placed in a way that could confuse. maybe I should simply run two separate calls.

Comment: OK. Maybe I misunderstand your question. Do you want the condition column go to the headers? In which case you should be able to chain `%>% spread(condition, mean)` after either of the options above.

Comment: I think the reason I wasn't more specific in my question is that I am quite open as to how it comes out. I was taken by all the ravings about summarizing data with dplyr and though it logical that I wanted a _mean_ at different levels of aggregation, i.e one table showing the over all mean and then the men broken down by sub-group. It's that not I need the condition column to go somewhere specific. If anything I am looking for a simple solution.